# Mysql query to get one to many relation and scan to struct

Tags: mysql, sql, go

I have 2 tables

```
person {
  id
} 

email {
  email 
  person_id
}
```

where person and email has one to many relationship.

I have Go struct

```
type Person struct {
  ID string
  Emails []*string
}
```

I would like to make 1 query and scan into `Person` struct with emails in array.

```
rows, _ := db.QueryContext(ctx, statement, ...)

people := []*Person{}

for rows.Next() {
  var person *Person
  rows.Scan(&person.ID, &person.Emails) // this can change as needed
  people = append(people, person)
}
return people
```

What will be the query in order to achieve this? What else has to change in Go code?

Answer (score 0):

This is really more of SQL question. There are a few ways to do what you want on the SQL side, and a few ways to do it on the Go side.

On the SQL side, maybe you'll do a `JOIN` on both tables (or if you're using foreign keys or some other constraint, just `SELECT` the `email` table) and sort through the data in Go. Another option would be to do multiple queries (perhaps with a prepared statement).

```golang
type Person struct {
  ID string
  Emails []string // doesn't need to be a pointer to a string
}

rows, _ := db.Query(`SELECT person.id, email.email FROM person JOIN email ON person.id = email.person_id`)
peopleMap := make(map[int]*Person)

for rows.Next() {
    p := struct{ID int, Email string}{} // anonymous temporary struct
    rows.Scan(&p.ID, &p.Email)
    
    if !peopleMap[p.ID] { // check if person has been added to map yet
      peopleMap[p.ID] = &Person{ID: p.ID, Emails: make([]string, 0, 1)}
    }
    peopleMap[p.ID].Emails = append(peopleMap[p.ID].Emails, p.Email)
}

// then either use the map directly or convert it to an array.
```

The other option would be to do a new query for every person to get just their emails in the result set.